# Get the current User's employee's ID in XML File odoo 10

Tags: xml, filter, odoo, searchview, odoo-10

I my My model i have a field 'mentor_id' that is defined as :

```
mentor_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Mentor')
```

In My SearchView i need to add a filter that only shows records with mentor_id = Current user's Employee_id
so i added :

```
<filter string="My :" name="my" domain="[('mentor_id','in',uid.employee_ids)]"/>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, i get this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to evaluate search criterions: 
{"code":400,"message":"Evaluation Error","data":{"type":"local_exception","debug":"Local evaluation failure\nAttributeError: object has no attribute 'employee_ids'\n\n{\"domains\":[[],\"[('mentor_id','in',uid.employee_ids)]\"],\"contexts\":[{\"lang\":\"en_US\",\"tz\":false,\"uid\":1,\"params\":{\"action\":324}},{}],\"group_by_seq\":[]}"}}
```

uid refers to the current user isn't? So why the error says :"The object has no attribute 'employee_ids'".
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the view, you'll only be getting the current user id through `user.id`
I have not tested but it might happen that you will get the current user object in the `user` variable in the view. And you can use `user.employee_id` in the domain.

If this not happens what you can do is:

- Create a Many2one relation with `res.users` with a compute attribute pointing to a function.
- Write `self.*feild_name* = self.env.user` inside the function. You'll get the current user object in the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should write down the user id of the mentor on the employee itself. It will be easier. Just add a related field (you don't need to set/show it, just add the field in python code and it's done) :

```
mentor_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Mentor')
mentor_user_id = fields.Many2one(
    related='mentor_id.user_id', store=True, readonly=True)
```

And just use this filter instead

```
<filter string="My :" name="my" domain="[('mentor_user_id', '=', uid)]"/>
```

Comment: @CherifOdoo Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look again at the error you're receiving.

> object has no attribute `employee_ids`

This suggests that you haven't added your `employee_ids` field onto the `res.users` model (which is what `uid` pulls up).

Can you post your full model so we can get a better idea of the relationships going on?